# How to increase M2 Product Upsert Performance?

Tags: magento2, product, integration

I upsert products like this:

```
try {
    $newProduct = $this->productRepository->get($productData['sku']);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    $newProduct = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();
}
$newProduct->setAttributeSetId($this->getAttributeSetIdFromLabel($productData['attribute_set']));

foreach ($straightAttributes as $attribute) {
    if (isset($productData[$attribute])) {
        $newProduct->setData($attribute, $productData[$attribute]);
    }
}
$savedProduct = $this->productRepository->save($newProduct);
```

This works, but is not performance enough. It takes me more than 8 seconds for each product in my local environment. This is too slow for my requirements: **I need it for integrations, and would expect it to take less than a second in my local, and be even faster in an appropriately sized environment**.

Are there simple ways to increase the performance, without switching to queues? Maybe I just do it the wrong way...?

---

Update: I've got a suggestion, now, open for feedback!

If I update only one attribute of a product, then the `saveAttribute` method of the product resource (~ 0.02s) is significantly faster than the `save` method of the product repository (~ 8s):

```
$newProduct = $this->productRepository->get($productData['sku']);
$myAttribute = 'ean13';
$newProduct->setData($myAttribute, '1234567890123');
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
 */
$productResource->saveAttribute($newProduct, $myAttribute);
```

This is great so far, but unfortunately, that `saveAttribute` method can handle only one attribute per call. If I want to update 30 attributes, that method has to be called 30 times. Not too difficult to implement with a loop, one could say. But the dark side of this workaround are the resulting 30 sql requests, which might sum up in a larger installation with some thousands of products to be updated.

I could reduce the number of SQL requests by checking the difference between `$newProduct->get...()` and the new value to be written. If I use the `saveAttribute` method only in cases where the two values differ, I can probably save a lot of time (depending on the number of values changed).

Still, that solution is not perfect yet: Some field values cannot be updated via the `saveAttribute` method. One example is the *sku* (see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7247); I also had issues with the *attribute set*. And then, there are the more complex "attributes". It gets fancy, where the assignment of products to websites is required to be changed dynamically: While this can be done easily via the `save` method ...

```
$myProduct->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);
$savedProduct = $this->productRepository->save($myProduct);
```

... the `saveAttribute` method horribly fails. It is meant to fail, because it is not much more than a wrapper for some upsert queries in the product attribute tables, - and that's not where the assignment of products to websites is stored.

Can one still make use of the significant performance advantages of the `saveAttribute` method for a product integration?

I would assume that one can check all conditions first, and go for the `saveAttribute` path only, if all changes on the product can be handled by the `saveAttribute` method:

```
if (!storeAssignmentHasChanged() && !complexProductAttributesHaveChanged()) {
  // saveAttribute
} else {
  setData...
  save...
}
```

All this seems, however, a bit too much for a simple product upsert task. Are there ideas to simplify it?

---

Update:

My colleague suggested to create a product with very "required attributes only", and then use the attribute update methods for all changes.

I've tried that out in a gist https://gist.github.com/kmddevdani/fd0c068e9bb36fec905ce259b44b13f5. It does create products, but still, the `save` is quite slow (around 22 seconds in my local environment).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already found a solution for this, but if not, I suggest you take a look at `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action::updateAttributes`.
This was present in the codebase since 2011, so should be still relevant.

You could send in the `$productIds` param an array with only one product ID, and in the `$attrData` param a list of attributes as `key => value` (see `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action::updateAttributes` how the attributes are updated).

This of course means that the product should still exist, otherwise how would you update a product that doesn't exist?

I think this logic would make sense:
If new ->  create product with all attributes
If existing -> update only attributes

> My colleague suggested to create a product with very "required attributes only", and then use the attribute update methods for all changes.

I don't think this will make a difference, but I may be wrong, so worth giving a try if it makes a difference when creating a new product.
(the only thing I could think of is that for products with a larger amount of data, i.e. attributes, it would take more time to save, so creating it first with only the required attributes may make more sense)